# In bash, why don't I need to escape nested quotes?

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a variable named `formatted_deploy_history` that has multi-lined content.  I'm trying to pipe that content into a series of commands and save the end result to a variable.  Here's what I've done:

```
nwhin_version="$(echo "${formatted_deploy_history}" | grep "productName" | grep "NHINC" | head -n1 | grep -o "[0-9]*")"
```

This works the way I want, but it seems like it should be a syntax error.  Why is it that the second quote doesn't interfere with the rest of the command?  I'd expect a syntax error because this would be interpreted like this:

```
nwhin_version="$(echo "
```

with trailing characters.

Comment: FYI -- `echo | grep | grep | head | grep -o` is kinda' silly. You should be able to do all of this with one command, particularly if you're willing to use bashisms like `[[ $formatted_deploy_history =~ $your_regex_here ]]` and then referring to `$BASH_REMATCH` to get content extracted in a regex group. Also, this is much more efficient than starting a pipeline of five subprocesses and waiting for them all to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains command substitution (`$(...)`), which is its own world - delimited by `$(` and `)`.

Inside that world, you're free to use double quotes without escaping.

Comment: Is there a more generic rule at play here, or is this just something special about `$(...)`?

Comment: @tieTYT, it is indeed something special about command substitution, whether used with the modern `$()` syntax or the ancient backtick-based one. That said, there are lots of places where a new quoting context is created -- command substitution isn't even nearly the only one.

Answer (score 2):

See section 2.3, "Token Recognition", in the [POSIX Shell Command Language specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html):

> If the current character is an unquoted `$` or `, the shell shall identify the start of any candidates for parameter expansion ( Parameter Expansion), command substitution ( Command Substitution), or arithmetic expansion ( Arithmetic Expansion) from their introductory unquoted character sequences: `$` or `${`, `$(` or ```, and "$((", respectively. The shell shall read sufficient input to determine the end of the unit to be expanded (as explained in the cited sections). **While processing the characters, if instances of expansions or quoting are found nested within the substitution, the shell shall recursively process them in the manner specified for the construct that is found.** The characters found from the beginning of the substitution to its end, allowing for any recursion necessary to recognize embedded constructs, shall be included unmodified in the result token, including any embedded or enclosing substitution operators or quotes. The token shall not be delimited by the end of the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need quotes around the command substitution.

Try this:

```
nwhin_version=$(echo "${formatted_deploy_history}" | grep "productName" | grep "NHINC" | head -n1 | grep -o "[0-9]*")
```

Comment: This is true -- in the specific case of an assignment, outer quotes are optional.

Comment: helpful? consider upvoting :)

Comment: I'm not sure that it is helpful -- the goal is to understand a piece of behavior, as opposed to trying to avoid that behavior. Even if not helpful, though, it is indeed true. :)